# Random Numbers for x,y within boundary

Tags: python, random, points

I would like to generate random numbers for x,y within a certain bound. There already exist values for x,y which gives the boundary for the given object, see Figure. [image]

Now the goal is to generate more points within the bound. Unfortunately I dont know how to do this.

Any help is appreciate it.

Comment: add the code that gives the boundary for the given object so we can know what you got and how to continue

Comment: Do you have (or could create) a function that returns True if x, y is inside the boundary and False otherwise?  If so, you could create random x, y over the grid range until a point is inside the boundary.

Comment: Sam Mason you are the hero today. Problem solved, thanks.